# python: changing a variable to rerun the script in a infinite loop

Tags: python, web-scraping

Basicly I'm trying to take a starting variable run it through my code. 
Then add 1 to the variable and rerun the code and repeat till i stop it. Now i have wrote this up but its pretty off from what I'm trying to accomplish. Am i on the right path or completely off?

CODE -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

start = 1
print("starting number: ", start)
i = 0
number = 500
while i < number:
    url = "https://randomsite.com/{0}".format(start + i)
try:
    print(int(start) + i)

    response1 = requests.get(url)
    name = re.findall(('analyticsKey":"([^"]+)'), response1.text)
    ids = re.findall(('id":"([^"]+)'), response1.text)
    print(name)
    print("")
    print(ids)
    print("")
except:
    pass
i += 1
```

Comment: Your indentation is off. Everything after the line `url = ....` needs to be indented an extra level. Also, this is the perfect use case for a `for` loop. Try replacing the while statement with `for i in range(500)` and get rid of `i = 0` and `i += 1`.

Comment: it could be easier to use a for loop with range, like  `for i in range(500):`

Comment: Also, bare `except` is bad practice, you should use named Exceptions. And why are you doing `int(start)`? `start` is already an `int`.

Comment: And you should try to re-write those 4 `print` calls as a single call: it will take less space & be more efficient.

Comment: @DBrowne thank you so much for the help and extra explanation, PRMoureu and PM 2Ring thank you as well.